# C++ and C# COM Interop, importing the TLB Error C1083

Tags: c#, visual-c++, com-interop

I'm using VS2013, and have a solution that has a C++ Project that references the TLB file from a C#.,dll project in the same solution.

My import statement

```
#import "Toolbox.Accessor.tlb" named_guids
```

in the C++ project cannot find the TLB.  I get the compile time error `error C1083: Cannot open type library file: 'Toolbox.Accessor.tlb': No such file or directory`

While I totally understand the error message, what I don't know how to do is to get the .TLB file into the proper place, so that the C++ Compiler can find it.

I want to do this at compile time so that it will pull the generated TLB file from the C# project and will work on my build server.

I've referenced the C# Dll project as a Reference to the C++ project, and have searched the web for an answer, but alas, have found none to this point.

Comment: Use regasm.exe with the /tlb flag (see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx) in a postbuild event of your C# project, maybe?

Comment: Just add the C# project's output directory to the "Additional Include Directories" setting so the C++ compiler can find that .tlb file.  Something like `..\CsharpProjectName\bin\$(Configuration)`.  And add the project dependency so the C# project is always built first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is the proper inclusion of the Additional Include Directories setting.  As HansPassant pointed out in a comment..

The final answer for me was to define an include directory as follows:

```
$(OutDir)..\..\MyCSharpProject\bin\$(Configuration)
```

This works both on my individual developer system, and the build server which isn't putting any changed files into the original Source Folders, but is putting them in a BuildArtifacts folder.